# Svg element and browser compatibility

Tags: svg, cross-browser

I have a SVG logo for my site under construction. The logo looks good in chrome but in firefox its cut off. Can someone advise me whats happening. I am unable to diagnose the issue. Your helps is much appreciated

The log is on the header 
http://demo.thesomerset.com/rosalie/

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the value of the svg viewBox until the logo fits. Note the values made larger will reduce its size. The current value is viewBox="0 0 231.3 119". Changing it to  viewBox="0 0 462.6 238" would reduce its size by half.